# Setting up a java/j2ee development environment with: Eclipse, Tomcat and Vagrant

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, virtualbox, vagrant

I would like to use **Vagrant** ([See here](http://www.vagrantup.com/)) together with **VirtualBox** in order to set up a java development environment to work on webapps (***.war** archives for that matter).

I would have **Eclipse** installed on the host and **MySql** on the guest (that's pretty straightforward so far) but I want to have **Tomcat** run on the guest too and that where it is getting more difficult.

My questions are:

- What files/folders am I supposed to share? (not the whole eclipse workspace I suppose)
- Am I better off using a exploded or a normal war archive?
- How do I configure Eclipse (which lives on the host) to see the remote Tomcat (the one that lives on the guest).

Is all of this really feasible with Vagrant?

**EDIT 1**: Here is a screen capture of my Eclipse's Tomcat:

[image: screen capture of my tomcat]

Answer (score 4):

**What files/folders am I supposed to share? (not the whole eclipse workspace I suppose)**

IMHO, share `the project you are working on` is enough.  This way you may have one VM for each project.

You have two options to generate the war:

1. build on host;
2. build on VM (preferred).

If you choose `Option 1`: Since your project folder is shared with VM, you can copy the war to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` once you ssh to VM.

I would suggest `Option 2` because you could keep the build environment as close to your production environment as possible.

**Am I better off using a exploded or a normal war archive?**

I would use normal war archive, but there's not much difference here.

**How do I configure Eclipse (which lives on the host) to see the remote Tomcat (the one that lives on the guest).**

You have two options here:

1. Setup port forwarding in vagrantfile;
2. Setup a private network, which is my preferred way since you don't have to forward every single port manually if more than one services running on VM need to be accessed from host machine.

**How to configure Host-Only Networks**

`config.vm.network "hostonly", "192.168.0.0"`

Have this line in your `Vagrantfile` will instruct vagrant to create a private network that has a static IP address: `192.168.0.0`

The IP address of the host is always the same IP address but with the final octet as a 1. In the preceding example, the host machine would have the IP address `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply Mingyu. A few questions about the eclipse workspace. My app is currently here: `/home/julien/Documents/workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myProject` Is this what I am supposed to share?

Comment: I have just spent some time playing with Vagrant. It is wonderful. The limitation is rather on the Eclipse/Tomcat side insofar as one cannot add a remote tomcat in eclipse. The only way is to use maven from eclipse but this is not a very comfortable way of coding...

Comment: I think your path should be something like `/home/julien/Documents/workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/myProject`.

Comment: I usually clone project from git repo, and add it to eclipse as external project.  So my path is like `/home/julien/myProject`.

Comment: Umm... It seems to boil down to the fact that Tomcat cannot be separated from Eclipse if one is to use and control Tomcat from within Eclipse. Doesn't it?

Comment: I publish war via `ant`, so for me this doesn't seem to be an issue.  Do you use some sort of Eclipse-Tomcat plugin to publish the war?

Comment: I have added a picture of my Eclipse-tomcat. This is how I use Tomcat from Eclipse... Do you see my point?